# Is it valid to have a function return type as 'long' while taking integer parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it legal to use a function return type as `long` while taking integer parameters?

```
using System;

class Application
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Calculator obj = new Calculator();
        Console.WriteLine("2 + 3 = {0}", obj.Add(2, 3));
        Console.WriteLine("3 - 2 = {0}", obj.Subtract(3, 2));
    }
}

class Calculator
{
    public long Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public long Subtract(int c, int d)
    {
        return c - d;
    }
}
```

The functions `Add` and `Subtract` take integer parameters but return a `long`. The operations themselves involve simple addition and subtraction of integers. The code seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if this is considered good practice, or if there are potential pitfalls I should be aware of.

Is it valid to have a function with a long return type while dealing with integer parameters? Are there any performance or readability implications, or is there a more idiomatic way to handle such scenarios in C#?

I appreciate any insights or best practices related to this coding pattern.

Comment: Of course it's legal, just set `a` and `b` to `int.MaxValue`  then the sum can't fit in `int` but works fine with `long`.

Comment: @PoulBak It doesn't work fine as written. They will overflow the integer's normal range and give the wrong answer unless you cast at least one of the operands to `long` _before_ doing the operation.

Comment: why returning a long if the result is an int ? makes sense ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Because the adding two int values could create a value larger than would normally fit in an int. Similarly, subtracting two int values could create a value smaller than would normally fit.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn agree and makes sense but it could overflow as PoulBak described

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: You're right, one of the values needs to be cast.

Comment: What do you mean by "legal" or "valid"? Can you not run this code yourself and see if it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is legal, and also useful when you can have results exceeding what an `int` can handle on its own... but you need to cast one operand to get results that are guaranteed to match normal arithmetic in all cases:

```
public long Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + (long)b;
}

public long Subtract(int a, int b)
{
    return a - (long)b;
}
```

See it here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/05d76W

Answer (score 0):

You can Seize BigInteger struct from [System.Numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-8.0) and the Add,Subtract implementation as:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         Calculator obj = new Calculator();
        Console.WriteLine("2 + 3 = {0}", obj.Add(2, 3));
        Console.WriteLine("3 - 2 = {0}", obj.Subtract(3, 2));
    }
}

class Calculator
{
    public BigInteger Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return  BigInteger.Add(new BigInteger(a),new BigInteger(b));
    }

    public BigInteger Subtract(int c, int d)
    {
        return BigInteger.Subtract(new BigInteger(c),new BigInteger(d));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is not *illegal*, consider your business/desired logic and ask yourself it is makes sense?

As others have mentioned, not converting and returning a `long` could result in an unexpected (wrong) value being returned

For illustrative purposes lets consider your `Add` function and the maximum value of the `int` type.

```
Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue); // 2147483647
```

```
public int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue, 1); // -2147483648
```

The value returned above is likely not what you or your users expected.

Therefore if your business logic allows and expects numbers to exceed the max value of an `int`, why not just work with `long` in the first place and keep things consistent.

If not exceeding the max value of `int` is a requirement of your business logic, then consider validating values before they are passed to your functions and using exceptions should an overflow occur.